# Modelling time for complex events generated out of simple ones

Tags: apache-flink

My flink application generates output (complex) events based on the processing of (simple) input events. The generated output events are to be consumed by other external services. My application works using event-time semantics, so I am bit in doubt regarding what should I use as the output events' timestamp.

Should I use:

- the processing time at the moment of generating them?
- the event time (given by the watermark value)?
- both? (*)

For my use case, I am using both for now. But maybe you can come up with examples/justifications for each of the given options.

(*) In the case of using both, what naming would you use for the two fields? Something along the lines of *event_time* and *processing_time* seems to leak implementation details of my app to the external services...

Comment: What are Your concerns here? What are you going to do with events? Do You need event time downstream ?? How do You create complex events from simple ones ?? Do simple events have timestamps ??

Comment: Hi Dominik. Sorry for leaving my question so open...My main concern is that I am a bit hesitant to include the processing time at all in my case. Input events have their own timestamp, and the output events are generated from the input ones plus some kind of rule for detecting certain patterns/sequences. I guess including both is a safe bet, but I am questioning to myself whether it makes sense to include the processing time in the first place...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no general answer to your question. It often depends on downstream requirements. Let's look at two simple cases:

- A typical data processing pipeline is ingesting some kind of movement event (e.g., sensor data, click on web page, search request) and enriches it with master data (e.g., sensor calibration data, user profiles, geographic information) through joins. Then the resulting event should clearly have the same time as the input event.
- A second pipeline is aggregating the events from the first pipeline on a 15 min tumbling window and simply counts it. Then fair options would be to use the start of the window or the time of the first event, end of the window or time of the last event, or both of these information. Using the start/end of a window would mean that we have a resulting signal that is always defined. Using the first/last event timestamp is more precise when you actually want to see in the aggregates when things happen. Usually, that also means that you probably want some finer window resolutions though (1 min instead of 15 min). Whether you use the start or the end of a window is often more a matter of taste and you are usually safer to include both.

In none of these cases, processing time is relevant at all. In fact, if your input is event time, I'd argue that there is no good reason for processing time. The main reason is that you cannot do meaningful reprocessing with processing time.

You can still add processing time, but for a different reason: to measure the end-to-end latency of a very complex data analytics pipeline including multiple technologies and jobs.

Comment: Thanks Arvid, I realize that this is very application-specific. To give you more context, in my case input events come with their own timestamps, and the output ones are generated out of them plus some rules for detecting certain patterns/sequences. It might be something as simple as `cpu.usage > .8` but also something more elaborate such as the combination of certain events happening in certain order and within a given time frame. It basically depends on each rule. So far I am attaching two timestamps to the output events, consisting of the processing time and event-time watermark...

Comment: ...but your comment arguing that processing time plays no role at all makes me question whether I should just use the event-time watermark value within my Flink app at the time of generating the output event as the only timestamp value. Using the first and last events' timestamps as you mention would be difficult in my case...so my options are whether to use the processing time, the watermark value, or both.

Comment: I see watermark as something purely technical and rather random when it comes to applying logic. Depending on how the watermark is generated, your records will look different if executed several times. That's something I'd avoid as much as possible, as it will make testing a nightmare. What's your understanding of watermark and why it's useful here?

Comment: In order to tolerate certain out-of-orderness in the input events, I'm using a watermark generator that basically waits for events in order to tolerate a given max lag (let's say, 30 secs). So, one option for me is to attach this value in the output events as the event-time value within my app at the time of generating the output event. I see your point about this value not being deterministic...maybe I could use the timestamp of the last input event triggering the output event. I agree on that using the watermark value is a bit weird since this is an internal concern of my app...

Comment: On the other hand, why should testing be a nightmare? Eg, one could just ignore any ts on the output events, and just focus on that given certain input events, certain output events are expected (modulo their time information). Instead of completely disregarding the ts in the output events, one could require that it has to be >= to that in the last input event triggering it. In my case I want to process data in real time, reprocessing data (input events) should not happen. That is why I am currently using the processing time as the output event ts, plus adding the wm to know how fresh it is.

Comment: Yes, you could simply ignore timestamps in your tests. But then of course, your timestamps are untested ;). Also depending on your data model and frequency of updates, it just might easier to maintain tests for complete equality vs. test each field - timestamp. I had some projects where we did selective tests and quite often new features (fields) did not lead to modified/new tests because the old ones still passed. Of course, that inevitably led to corrupted data in production.

Comment: Thanks Arvid for your several comments. I guess in my case the best thing I can do is to use the timestamp of the latest input event finally triggering an output event as the timestamp for it. For example, if we want to detect "A followed by B followed by C", and that happens, use the timestamp in C as the one for the generated output event. This would be completely deterministic and would allow for strict equality checks within the tests.

Comment: Yes, and it may also be conceptionally the soundest option. You create a new event, right at the (event) time, you received C. That would also make it possible to aggregate several events being generated at that time in a sound manner.

Comment: Agreed, thanks a lot again (someday I'll buy you a coffee, or two!)